# Move angry birds progress from one device to another (cross-platform)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ios, angry-birds

I was playing angry birds on iPhone, now I am selling my iPhone 3GS on ebay because I got an android (galaxy nexus).

Is there any way to transfer progress in the game over to new phone?  I like the game but I don't think I could really be bothered playing all again up to where I was at..

Comment: Well half of this at least is more of an iOS question. Can you access the save file on the iPhone in any way? If not then the Android half (getting it onto the right spot on the new device) is kind of moot.

Comment: I'm not sure but the game does sync scores and achievements to some server - so I thought that data may also be accessible from android version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1353754) thread on xda-developers. If you have jail broken iPhone and rooted Android phone, you can transfer your progress.

Basically you have to copy two files, highscores.lua and settings.lua from /private/var/mobile/Applications/(very long string)/Documents from iPhone and replace them on Android phone in /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/. You also have to fix permission and make sure you've completed at least 1 level in Android phone before replacing the two files.

If you trust yourself you can also use programs like [Angry birds unlock all level](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pommedeterresautee.angrybirdsunlock) in Android and unlock only up to the level you've completed in iPhone. But you won't have exact score and hidden star collections. So though little troublesome the earlier way might be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no guarantee that the information is stored in the same format between multiple platforms. But also there isn't a way to browse the data files on ios or access the file system. Unless you are rooted, I don't think you have access to where the data files are stored on android either. Either way, you are sort of stuck.

The game data is stored locally on the devices, not on a remote server. They should store it on a server, especially now that the game is available to play on both Google+ and Facebook as well as the mobile devices.